# Confounding performance gap between Angular & Blazor client sid

Tags: angular, performance, blazor-client-side

I am executing the same small piece of code in Angular & in Blazor (Client side) and I do not understand the gap of performance between the 2 systems.
Angular look much much faster.

I am using the last up-to-date version of Windows 10 (1903).
I am using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Build officiel) (64 bits).

The Code is very very simple :
For Blazor

```
@code {
    int currentCount = 0;

    void process()
    {
        DateTime from = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine (from);

        long nombreOccurences = 100000000;
        Console.WriteLine ("Nombre de factoriels " + nombreOccurences );

        for (int currentCount = 0; currentCount < nombreOccurences; currentCount++) {
            long result = factorial(currentCount%21);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(currentCount);

        DateTime to = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine (to);

        TimeSpan diff = to - from;
        Console.WriteLine("diff " + diff);
    }

    long factorial (long n) {
        return n>1 ? n*factorial(n-1) : 1;
    }
}
```

For Angular

```
process() {
    let currentCount = 0;
    let result = 0;

    console.log('Process');

    const from = new Date();
    console.log('from', from);

    const nombreOccurences = 100000000;
    console.log('Nombre de factoriels ', nombreOccurences);

    for (currentCount = 0; currentCount < nombreOccurences; currentCount++) {
      result = this.factoriel(currentCount % 21);
    }

    console.log ('currentCount', currentCount);

    const to = new Date();
    console.log(to);

    var diff = to.getTime() - from.getTime();
    console.log('diff ', diff);
}

public factoriel(n: number) {
    return n > 1 ? n * this.factoriel(n - 1) : 1;
}
```

Console of Angular :

```
from Thu Aug 08 2019 16:21:35 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
app.component.ts:22 Nombre de factoriels  10000000
app.component.ts:28 currentCount 10000000
app.component.ts:31 Thu Aug 08 2019 16:21:36 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
app.component.ts:34 diff  795
```

Console of Blazor :

```
ASM: ﻿08/08/2019 14:23:54
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: Nombre de factoriels 100000000
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: 0
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: 08/08/2019 14:24:52
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: diff 00:00:58.2570000
```

Comment: Interesting test, try without outputting to the console and see if it comes closer. If that's the case the issue is context switching between Web Assembly and JavaScript. Let us know

Comment: I can re-run  without the output, but I do not understandand your remark. 
The time costing step is the loop, and there is no console output, no switch JS/WebAssembly inside this loop.

Comment: Now I checked the code, you are right console log are not placed in the loop so shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor Webassembly is pretty slower than JavaScript. See https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/9825.

**But**, now , you can use Blazor WebAssembly ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation, there is no big gap with JavaScript, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/